# Unable to change current extjs theme in app

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have an already configurated ExtJS 5 who seems to have one workspace with one custom theme.

This custom theme (x-theme) is placed here:

```
extjs/x-workspace/packages/x-theme
```

And I am trying to change the theme from ext-theme-neptune to ext-theme-gray, here:

```
extjs/x-workspace/packages/x-theme/package.json
```

Where I have changed the following argument:

```
"extend": "ext-theme-neptune"
```

to

```
"extend": "ext-theme-gray"
```

After changing this, seeing no changes in webgui, I tried to re build doing,

```
sencha app refresh
sencha app build
```

in,

```
extjs/x-workspace/x
```

but got several errors and a big BUILD FAILED:

```
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[ERR] C2000: Rhino Parse Error (illegal character => Mac OS X           2??ATTR?xPuTTYThis resource fork intentionally left blank   ??) -- /home/user/x/static/extjs/x-workspace/x/app/model/production/._BenchModel.js:1:1
[ERR] C2000: Rhino Parse Error (Compilation produced 1 syntax errors. => null) -- /home/user/x/static/extjs/x-workspace/x/app/model/production/._BenchModel.js:1
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
```

From [Sencha Documention for themes](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/guides/core_concepts/theming.html) I cannot find anything more than I have already done.

Any of you with more experience can highlight me on how to change ExtJS theme?

Thanks in advance!

**Note 1:** I have no experience in ExtJS.

**Note 2:** There is no documentation left by the person who have setup ExtJS in first place.

UPDATE 1:

I was able to bypass those errors, but now I am getting the following:

> [ERR] C2000: Rhino Parse Error (missing ; before statement =>
>   let record = me.up().record;) --
>   /home/user/x/static/extjs/x-workspace/x/app/view/production/JobFormDetails.js:130:23
>   [ERR] C2000: Rhino Parse Error (missing ; before statement =>
>   let message = '';) --
>   /home/user/x/static/extjs/x-workspace/x/app/view/production/JobFormDetails.js:131:24
>   [ERR] C2000: Rhino Parse Error (Compilation produced 2 syntax errors.
>   => null) -- /home/user/x/static/extjs/x-workspace/x/app/view/production/JobFormDetails.js:1
>   [ERR] [ERR] BUILD FAILED

where in that JobFormDetails I have this part that has missing statements, but cannot figure what where is missing ';' :

```
listeners:{
    beforerender:function(me){
        'use strict';
        let record = me.up().record;
        let message = '';
        console.log(me);
        console.log('and this is record');
        console.log(me.up().record);
        console.log('this is record');
        console.log(record);
        if (record) {
            const recDate = new Date(record.date);
            const now = new Date();
            message = 'Job production is running';
            if (recDate > now) {
                message = 'Job scheduled to start on ' + record.date;
            }
            if (record.closed === true) {
                message = 'Job completed';
            }
            record.total_quantity_status = 'Total production: ' + record.quantity + ' parts';
        } else {
            record = {};
        }
        record.status = message;
        me.getForm().setValues(record);
    }
}
```

**Note 3:** I am not a JS expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are doing everything right. But you have an error in the model file `/home/user/x/static/extjs/x-workspace/x/app/model/production/._BenchModel.js` in your application.

Comment: I was able to bypass some errors, but now I am getting 'missing ; before statement' but cannot figure what is it. =/  I have updated my question with a full description.

Comment: try remove 'use strict'

Comment: Seems like using those types of variable inicializations 'let' and 'const' was an issue to sencha console. After remove those resolve the situation, being able to build a new webgui, thanks pvlt!